# Implementing a stack in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, stack, push

I am a college student trying to implement a stack in my data structures course. My professor is making us implement a stack using inheritance. I'm not used to using inheritance and extending classes so I am a little confused about what his TODO: comments are specifying. I think I only need advice with the first one or two comments and then I should be able to figure the rest out.

I filled in how I think I should do it but the way it's worded makes me feel like I am doing it wrong. I don't understand why "super" and "this" are legal but not necessary? Does that mean I can just say add(item); and it will be fine?

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Stack<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    // TODO 1: declare a private integer member named "cursor" and initialize it to
    // -1

        private int cursor = -1;

    /**
     * Push the passed item of type T onto the stack. This is equivalent to calling
     * the add function inherited from ArrayList.
     *
     * @param item the item to be pushed onto the stack.
     */
    public void push(T item) {
        // TODO 2: add the item passed as a parameter using the add function inherited
        // from the ArrayList super class. Hint: it is legal but unnecessary to use the
        // syntax "super." or "this." to call the add function.
        super.add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `Stack extends ArrayList`

`Stack` does not override `add` function, so `super` is not neccessary.

With `super` you call function of extended class (`ArrayList`)